# PHP ERROR 500 but execution ok

Tags: php

I have a simple self-made MVC structure composed by Controllers, Models and Views.

It was working fine, but now one controller is performing very strange behaviour...

Script gives error 500 (if you check headers) but execution and output is ok.

No error messages, no error log, nothing...  but let me tell you the most strangest thing:

if I write debug directives for log information like these

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Then error 500 disapears... instead of displaying error information, and work like a charm.

Can't understand this situation.  Any help?

Regards

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: Probably try to change PHP Version or try it on different server if available.

Comment: Could it be calling `header('HTTP/1.1 500')`?

Comment: Take a look in the Server log

Comment: Yes, in localhost the problem does not occurs

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.  I was using a PHP include which contain some @ symbols, for example:  @file_get_contents...   This is a not recommended practice, now I know why :)

Thanks for your interest